# Storing formula in database and need to substitute values at runtime

Tags: java, regex

There is an entity which is an industrial part that I am storing in database. Based on user input we need to calculate the no of each industrial part required. We calculate this number based on formula that we are storing in db for each industrial part.

part1 -> formula = (input1+input2)/(input3)
part2 -> formula = (input1*input2*input3)

So when user enters input1=4 input2=6 input3=2
I need to call calculate the no of parts.
no of part1s - (4+6)/2 = 5
mo of part2s - (4*6*2) = 48

I could do this with String manipulation but that's becoming very complex because I have more than 7 user inputs and formulas are also very complex.

Is there any better way to do this.

**Update1** I tried to do this using java regex

```
                    String[] validInputs = {"halfs", "fulls", "noOfPartitions"};
    List<String> validInputsList = Arrays.asList(validInputs);
    HashMap inputMap = new HashMap();
    inputMap.put("halfs", 3);
    inputMap.put("fulls", 3);
    inputMap.put("noOfPartitions", 2);
    String formula = "(halfs+fulls)/noOfPartitions";
    Iterator iter = inputMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {

          String key = (String)iter.next();
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key);
            // get a matcher object
            Matcher m = p.matcher(formula);
            formula = m.replaceAll(inputMap.get(key).toString());

    }
    System.out.println(formula);
```

**Update2**
I actually needed this for a grails app. Below is what I ended up doing.

```
        def inputMap = ['halfs':3, 'fulls':3,'noOfPartitions':2]
def formula = '(halfs+fulls)/noOfPartitions'
inputMap.each { entry -> 

    def pat = ~entry.key
    assert pat instanceof java.util.regex.Pattern
    def matcher = (formula =~ /$pat/)
    formula = matcher.replaceAll((inputMap.get(entry.key)).toString())
    assert matcher instanceof java.util.regex.Matcher

}
System.out.println(formula)
Eval.me(formula)
```

Comment: Which solution was applied to this problem?

Comment: @vs_lala I used regex to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your formulas as groovy script.
2. Store the script in DB.
3. Java 6 has good support for dynamic languages. Here is the [tutorial that get you started](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JSR+223+Scripting+with+Groovy).

Here is the details tutorial. [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html)

Comment: you are asking me to put  the String manipulation logic in groovy or java script? I could that in Java as well right?